# Table tennis rubber not showing brand or model

Tags: rules, equipment, table-tennis, racket

Is it legal to use a rubber cut in a way that it doesn't show the brand or any other information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regulation 3.02.01 states that only table tennis rubbers authorized by the International Table Tennis Federation (ITTF) can be used in authorized events.

You must ensure that you attached them to your blade so that the ITTF logo and the maker's logo or trademark are clearly visible near the edge of the blade so that they can be checked by the umpire.